# Is there a way to improve the load of nosql db from Streamlit app?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, streamlit

I'm writing a streamlit app where I read  data from a nosql database
I need to find all value of my collection of data (26000)
I do this by a pymongo query when I run the app.

Very well.... I've tried this with a 2000+ rows and I have no problems, when I change collection such I said above, streamlit re-run in loop and web socket raise an error.

Is there a way to get a huge data from database and represent it on streamlit app as a dataframe without raise exception?

I have increase the size of the message by modifying the config setting for `server.maxMessageSize` but still dont work

Comment: Is your mongdb local or in the cloud? Be careful `(26000+rows)` can reach billions.

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful if you could include at least the error message itself to help narrow down the specific issue. From what I can tell, though, it seems like the overarching issue is that you're trying to send more data to Streamlit than is permitted by its max message size value. I'm assuming "I have increase the size of the message" means that you've tried modifying the config setting for `server.maxMessageSize` per the [Streamlit configuration guide](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/configuration), but if that is not the case then you should give that a try.

As you've got a huge amount of data, it might be best to give some form of pagination a try. That is: instead of sending the entire dataframe to Streamlit, you would instead send a section of it (a "page") and provide some way of switching between "pages", such as in the form of "previous page"/"next page" buttons. As an example, assuming you're loading your data in as a Pandas dataframe and have Streamlit imported as `st`, you could try encapsulating pagination into a function like this:

```py
def paginate_dataframe(df, page_size: int):
    # Determine the maximum number of pages we should experience
    from math import ceil
    n_pages = ceil(len(df)/page_size)
    last_page = n_pages - 1

    # Get current page, initializing the state of the value if necessary
    current_page = st.session_state.setdefault("current_page", 0)

    # Define callback functions for the previous/next buttons so they can adjust the current page
    def decrement_page():
        if st.session_state.current_page > 0:
            st.session_state.current_page -= 1

    def increment_page():
        if st.session_state.current_page < last_page:
            st.session_state.current_page += 1

    # Create previous/next buttons which will be disabled when on the first or last pages, respectively
    button_columns = st.columns(2)

    with button_columns[0]:
        st.button(
            label="previous page",
            on_click=decrement_page,
            disabled=(current_page <= 0),
        )

    with button_columns[1]:
        st.button(
            label="next page",
            on_click=increment_page,
            disabled=(current_page >= last_page),
        )

    page_start = current_page * page_size
    st.dataframe(df.iloc[page_start: page_start+page_size])

paginate_dataframe(df, page_size=5)
```